# AWS ECR renaming tag

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecr

According to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/retag-aws-cli.html, it describe how to retagging exist image's tag.

So I tried to execute command.

1. `MANIFEST=$(aws ecr batch-get-image --repository-name test --image-ids imageTag=latest --query 'images[].imageManifest' --output text)`
2. `aws ecr put-image --repository-name test --image-tag old-version --image-manifest "$MANIFEST"`

(This command find image that has `latest` and changed it to `old-version`)

Expected re-named tag is old-version.

But when I checked in ECR, it has both `latest` and `old-version`.

How can I delete `latest` tag and give it to `old-version` tag only?

Answer (score 0):

Run the command:

`aws ecr batch-delete-image --repository-name test --image-ids imageTag=latest`